# Display twig code written in a twig file

Tags: php, twig, interpreter

I am writting a tutorial and need to display some twig code... Problem: I'm writting that twig code on a twig view, so I need to find some way to write it raw, without interpretation.

Currently, I am using a [twig extension](https://github.com/kgilden/KGStaticBundle) to do the job:

```
$path = $this->kernel->locateResource($path, null, true);
return file_get_contents($path);
```

But I'm wondering if there is better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Twig has a built-in tag to to that job : [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html).

```
{% verbatim %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in seq %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
```